# How to use SVG-Uri in React-native or Expo?

Tags: svg, react-native, expo, react-native-ios

I downloaded the [`expo-svg-uri` module](https://github.com/thongdn-it/expo-svg-uri) to use the Svg image.

But the image doesn't come out right.

Code I failed:

```js
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <SvgUri
      width="200"
      height="200"
      source={require("../../image/minigroup.svg")}
    />
  </View>
```

> Failed Image

[image: svg]

> Original Image

[image: sucess image]

> this is my svgfile

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="80" height="183" viewBox="0 0 80 183">
    <defs>
        <circle id="b" cx="35" cy="35" r="35"/>
        <filter id="a" width="142.9%" height="142.9%" x="-21.4%" y="-21.4%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"/>
            <feGaussianBlur in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="5"/>
            <feColorMatrix in="shadowBlurOuter1" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.12 0"/>
        </filter>
        <circle id="d" cx="35" cy="34" r="24"/>
        <filter id="c" width="168.8%" height="168.8%" x="-28.1%" y="-28.1%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <feOffset dx="3" dy="3" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"/>
            <feGaussianBlur in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="5"/>
            <feColorMatrix in="shadowBlurOuter1" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.12 0"/>
        </filter>
        <circle id="f" cx="35" cy="34" r="12"/>
        <filter id="e" width="208.3%" height="208.3%" x="-45.8%" y="-45.8%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"/>
            <feGaussianBlur in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="4"/>
            <feColorMatrix in="shadowBlurOuter1" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.12 0"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <text fill="#646464" font-family="Bungee-Regular, Bungee" font-size="20" letter-spacing="-.375">
            <tspan x="6.107" y="163">Point</tspan>
        </text>
        <text fill="#3D3D3D" font-family="Bungee-Regular, Bungee" font-size="20" letter-spacing="-.375">
            <tspan x="20.282" y="140">Tap</tspan>
        </text>
        <g transform="translate(5 5)">
            <rect width="70" height="81" y="28" fill="#FFD90D" rx="12"/>
            <use fill="#000" filter="url(#a)" xlink:href="#b"/>
            <use fill="#FFD90D" xlink:href="#b"/>
            <use fill="#000" filter="url(#c)" xlink:href="#d"/>
            <use fill="#FFD90D" xlink:href="#d"/>
            <g>
                <use fill="#000" filter="url(#e)" xlink:href="#f"/>
                <use fill="#FFD90D" xlink:href="#f"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I don't have a path value, I'm only drawing it all. Are you saying this is possible?

Please help us a lot. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First**

- Drag your svg file into this online tool [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/)
- Switch to the Markup tab.
- Copy `d` attribute of the `path` xml tag.

**Second**

- Render your svg file directly using [react-native-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg)

*react-native-svg is already installed and linked if you're using expo*

Example that would render Home icon:

```
<Svg
  width="20"
  height="20"
  viewBox="0 0 512 512" // Has to be the same of the original svg file
>
  <Path
    d="M208 448V320h96v128h97.6V256H464L256 64 48 256h62.4v192z"
    fill="red"
  />
</Svg>
```

This 'd save you as well the cost of loading and reading file ...

Comment: Are you saying that I should make an icon using svg myself?

Comment: The moduel you're using is actually extracting the path of your svg file and pass it to react-native-svg ... it's a bridge ... so all you do is to get the path (d arg) of your minigroup.svg file and use it as I mentioned in the ex and that's it

Comment: If I need to extract path from the svg file and use it, how do I  extract it?

Comment: Use the online tool I mentioned in the answer SVGOMG

Comment: @ Hend El-Sahli Looking at my image, there is no path.

Comment: Switch to the Markup tab >> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1814.173" height="1814.173"><path d="M915.25..></path></svg> >> it's the content of the **d** attribute of the path tag

Comment: @ HendEl-Sahli I uploaded SVG file code to the question. Please look at that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193749/discussion-between-hend-el-sahli-and-hong-develop).

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli will this work with complex SVG files? I have tried to follow your instructions above but have multiple d arg values. Documentation on using SVG files in expo / react-native seems to be fairly sparse - is it not the recommended approach?

Comment: @Phobos When I'm having an svg file that has multiple d args ... I use a free tool called Inkscape to **merge** all paths into a single one ... and it works perfectly ... you could also render multiple `<Path>` if you'd like