# How to show SVG files in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg

I want to render images from SVG files generated by illustrator, I am using **react-native** 0.59, **react-native-svg** and **react-native-svg-uri**, 
Here's my jsx:

```
  <View style={styles.aboutSection}>
              <SvgUri
                width="150"
                height="150"
                source={require('../../assets/images/logo_blue.svg')}
              />
    </View>
```

and my SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Calque_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="-574 823.3 20 14" style="enable-background:new -574 823.3 20 14;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#2A327B;}
</style>
<g>
    <g transform="translate(-320.000000, -1983.000000)">
        <g transform="translate(40.000000, 1680.000000)">
            <path class="st0" d="M-284,1140.3c-7.4,0-10-7-10-7s3.4-7,10-7c6.7,0,10,7,10,7S-277.3,1140.3-284,1140.3L-284,1140.3z
                 M-284,1129.3c-2.2,0-4,1.8-4,4s1.8,4,4,4s4-1.8,4-4S-281.8,1129.3-284,1129.3L-284,1129.3z M-284,1135.3c-1.1,0-2-0.9-2-2
                s0.9-2,2-2s2,0.9,2,2S-282.9,1135.3-284,1135.3L-284,1135.3z"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

And is not showing when I debug, what I am missing and is there a better way to show images from SVG files?
Is converting them to jsx using  [SVGR](https://www.smooth-code.com/open-source/svgr/playground/) is a better approach or there are other ways to do so.

Comment: Looks like that repo is dead. There are some workarounds [here](https://github.com/vault-development/react-native-svg-uri/issues/150) but none worked for me. maybe you could check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55604442/2694189)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56248043/how-to-use-svg-uri-in-react-native-or-expo/56249438#56249438

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the package seems to be no more maintained, after a good time of searching around, I’ve eventually ended up with using custom  web fonts with the help of [react-native-icons](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/):

1. (Optional) Minimizing the size of SVG, I used for this purpose [SVG minizer](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/)
2. Convert fonts using [icomoon](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select)
3. Add generated font to **assets/fonts** folder in your root (or any other path)
4. Add a linker in your **packages.json**

```
    "rnpm": {
        "assets": [
        "./assets/fonts/"
        ]
    }
```

5. And link it using `react-native link`
6. To create a custom icon component I’ve used **react-native-icons**, it
   has a *createIconSetFromIcoMoon* function to render font generated from  IcoMoon, and also a one generated from [Fontello](http://fontello.com/)

In my custom component MyIcon.js, I also add the selection.json generated.

```
import { createIconSetFromIcoMoon } from 'react-native-vector-icons';
import MyIconConfig from '../../../selection.json';

const MyIcon = createIconSetFromIcoMoon(MyIconConfig, 'MyIcon-icons', 'MyIcon-icons.ttf');
 //name of font I used in the website to generate font and name of ttf files generated
export default MyIcon;
```

I use it in my component, I the names of icons I've found them in demo.html:

```
<MyIcon
 style={styles.customStyle}
 name="previous"
 size={18}
 color=’red’
/>
```

**Note:** Make sure you use version >**6.3.0** of **react-native-icons**, and link your assets by running:

```
react-native link ./assets/fonts/
```